# "Run app" shortcut randomly fails to INSTALL + RUN android app (android studio)

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm talking about the IDE action highlighted in image below:

[image]

Whenever I use the shortcut, sometimes it just installs and that's it. Then if I press it again, it then runs the app. The earlier behavior used to be Install + run app every time.

So, it's quite frustrating because five years of muscle memory has me relying on the shortcut functioning as expected and I can't get used to how it works right now because it is totally random.

Anybody else experiencing this? Have you found any fix?

I'm on the latest Android 4.0 (Canary 9).

Comment: Sometimes I get same behavior in AS 3.5

Comment: Thank you. I'm glad to know I'm not the only one going insane.